# Why is "Random weighted selection in Java" not a real question?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

[Random weighted selection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409652/random-weighted-selection-in-java) was closed as "not a real question". Why is that?

It asks if there is a framework or solution for randomly selecting weighted options in Java. Seems pretty clear to me what they are asking. And the answer is "no, there is no framework, but `NavigableMap` solves this".

Without mentioning that it has only one downvote against 22 upvotes, as of time of writing this.

Comment: Its a real question, but reads like a recommendation request. It probably should be reworded so that it doesn't get closed for *that* reason.

Comment: To me it looks like the wrong close reason was chosen (should be the requesting an off-site resource reason.) Though, with a small edit, it wouldn't even fit that close reason.

Comment: @KevinB: Did that one exist at that time? Anyway, the question is now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with the question:

- We don't do recommendation questions.  But, that doesn't mean we don't allow recommendations.
- There are no inputs, actual outputs, and expected outputs. How are we supposed to know that we "did it right"?

To get around recommendation problems, ask how you'd do something, but don't ask for a framework or library. If one of those solves your problem, someone will give it to you.

To get around the second issue, include your inputs and your expected outputs -- that's how we know when we've solved your problem.

I've edited the OP's question to try to address these issues, but I'm guessing since they didn't provide any of these values for us.